# Reading, manipulating and writing SQLServer DateTimeOffset fields in C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, datetime

SQLServer 2008 introduced a much welcome [DateTimeOffset field type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Version 3.5 upwards of .Net introduced a corresponding [DateTimeOffset structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

I am wondering how the same field is manipulated in C++. The [documentation for `CDBVariant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7yk8s5d.aspx) does not discuss DateTimeOffset.

How are DateTimeOffsets manipulated in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878122.aspx) MSDN page might be useful to you. It includes an example in c++ on how to use the new date/time structures. From the page description:

> This sample shows how to initialize the date/time data structures that
>   were added in SQL Server 2008. It then prepares the input values,
>   binds parameters, and executes the query. For more information about
>   using these types, see Date/Time Improvements (ODBC).

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't think to search for `SQL_SS_TIMESTAMPOFFSET_STRUCT`